# Getting Redux State in action creators without Redux-Thunk middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hi I am building a React/Redux app and wanted to get state values inside action creators. I can get state using Redux-Thunk middle ware like this

```
export const SOME_ACTION = 'SOME_ACTION';
export function someAction() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const {items} = getState().otherReducer;

    dispatch(anotherAction(items));
  }
}
```

I found some code on stackoverflow to import store in action creators, but somehow I need to know how to import store in action creators.

Is there a way to get state in action creators without using middle ware?

Comment: "Is there a way to get state in action creators without using middle ware?" why? I mean any specific reason you want to avoid `redux-thunk`.

Comment: yeah, I want to use redux-promises

Comment: Is there a way to get state in redux promises

Comment: @h_a86 `store.getState()` will give states.Selected the state that you want.

Comment: @Riyaj Khan How should I import store in actions?

Comment: You could use both middlewares together: thunk to access current state and promise to await for promises.

Comment: It seems that @YuryTarabanko is right, there is an issue on redux-promises repository about your problem https://github.com/acdlite/redux-promise/issues/20